# Загрузить url в webview без http:// https://

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Добрый день, у меня в файле json сохранены ссылки сайтов, которые я хочу открыть в webview. Ссылки сохранены без [http://или](http://%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) [https://.Пробовал](https://.%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB) как то так сделать но не получилось

```
if(!url.contains("http") || !url.contains("https")) {
        if(URLUtil.isHttpUrl(url)) {
            url = "http://www." + url;
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        else
        {
            url = "https://www."+url;
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
```

как можно открыть ссылки не зная они [http://или](http://%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) https://?

Answer (score 1):

Убирите `www.`Изза этого ссылка может не октрытся

Comment: так ссылка открывается но не в webview , а в браузере

Comment: @androidx Вам нужно установить клиента для веб вью: `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`